# Grails unit testing not working - NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestCase

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit

I am running a test on the User domain I created according to instructions in the book: "Grails in Action". Here is the code for the test

```
package com.grailsinaction

import grails.test.*

class UserIntegrationTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    void testFirstSaveEver() {
        def user = new User( userId: 'johnny', password: 'secret',
            homepage: 'http://www.johnnylovesblogging.com' )
        assertNotNull user.save()
        assertNotNull user.id

        def foundUser = User.get( user.id )
        assertEquals 'joe', foundUser.userId
    }
}
```

I run the code inside console after the `grails console` command and it raised an error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestCase

My code doesn't make use of the TestCase class referred to in the error message. Is there a problem in my dependency?

Comment: how did you run the test from inside the console?

Comment: You need to show more of the stacktrace, preferably the parts with useful information. Also, what version of Grails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grails by default comes with Spock for testing. The book speaks of Junit. You have to change your test case to extend `extends Specification` i.e `spock.lang.Specification` and change your asserts etc accordingly.